# Plot bar chart with last item in a secondary y-axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am using the code below to generate this plot: [image]
However, I'd like to have only the last values of data1 and data 2 (Column F) to use a secondary y-axis, because they are much higher than the previous values. Would anybody know how could I do that? I appreciate the help!

```
x_label = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
x_pos = np.arange(len(x_label))
data1 = [1,3,2,5,8,67]
data2 = [1,3,2,5,12,45]

# Build the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fontsize = 14
ax.bar(x_pos, data1, align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black',
       capsize=3, width=0.2, color='r', label='data1')
ax.bar(x_pos+0.2, data2, align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black',
       capsize=3, width=0.2, color='b', label='data2')

ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_label, fontsize=fontsize)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem finds two solutions: one is the left-right axis with different limits (first code below). The second consists in using logarithmic scale. Note that this second solution is often preferred.

**Solution 1: secondary axis (not the best)**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_label = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
x_pos = np.arange(len(x_label))
data1 = [1,3,2,5,8,67]
data2 = [1,3,2,5,12,45]

# Build the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fontsize = 14

ax2 = ax.twinx()

# all but F
ax.bar(x_pos[:-1], data1[:-1], align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black',
       capsize=3, width=0.2, color='r', label='data1')
ax.bar(x_pos[:-1]+0.2, data2[:-1], align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black',
       capsize=3, width=0.2, color='b', label='data2')

# F
ax2.bar([x_pos[-1]], [data1[-1]], align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black',
       capsize=3, width=0.2, color='r', label='data1')
ax2.bar([x_pos[-1]+0.2], [data2[-1]], align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black',
       capsize=3, width=0.2, color='b', label='data2')

ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_label, fontsize=fontsize)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This produces the image below. The issue is that we cannot tell which bars are belonging to the right axis, unless we change the color but in this case it won't correspond anymore with the color code of the left-bars.

[image: bar with twins axis]

**Solution 2: using a log scale (much cleaner)**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_label = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
x_pos = np.arange(len(x_label))
data1 = [1,3,2,5,8,67]
data2 = [1,3,2,5,12,45]

# Build the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fontsize = 14

ax.bar(x_pos, data1, align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black',
       capsize=3, width=0.2, color='r', label='data1')
ax.bar(x_pos+0.2, data2, align='center', alpha=0.5, ecolor='black',
       capsize=3, width=0.2, color='b', label='data2')

ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_label, fontsize=fontsize)
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Which produces this image below. Now every bars are shown on the same axis, with a log scale axe. Data with large dynamic range are often shown with log scale.

[image: bars with log scale]